# why we don't calculate global minimum or maximum with looking the plot

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, nonlinear-optimization

Sorry I'm kind of newbie on optimization. As you know we can plot the multivariate functions.
[example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDKJ0.png)

So we can see the global minumum and maximum. so why we run gradient descent to calculate it ?

Comment: what if there are 10 variables?

Comment: In fact the graph (when the number / type of variables allow that) is precious to isolate the areas with **local** max-min. Then an analitical method is necessary to establish **precise** location and value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are numerous problems with that approach:

- Considering a function of two variables (as in your example) or less, you can only plot a limited portion, which may restrict you to only being able to find local minima.
- A computer is ultimately going to plot your function in discrete steps, which might "obscure", or "smooth out" finer details of the function that you might be interested in.
- If there are more (potentially **a lot** more) than 2 variables, how are you planning to graph the function?
- There is a lot of nuance in optimization problems (convexity, compactness, lower semi-continuity, ...) which make realistic optimization problems much more difficult than what you are probably thinking of right now.

And probably many more that I don't know at the top of my head at the moment.